# How to stop interval in node js when browser close or change route by Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Here is my code snippet of my real project. A interval start when i go on page '/tracking' ,it's ok...

But when i go '/app' ,then interval also running. I know about interval is a global thing and close by `clearInterval(myTimer)` , my question is, in that scenario -

how to close interval when route change or close browser , thanks,

```
var express = require('express');
var app     = express();

app.get('/app', function(req, res) {
   res.send("this is app page");
 });


app.get('/tracking', function(req, res) {

    var myTimer= setInterval(function() {
        console.log("Tracking Start between 20 second interval")
    }, 20000);

    res.send('this is a tracking page!');  
});

//Lets define a port we want to listen to
const PORT = 3001;

app.listen(PORT);
console.log('Magic happens on port ' + PORT);
```

Comment: req.connection.on('close',function(){    
       clearInterval(myTimer)
    });

Answer (score 0):

```
var express = require('express');
var app     = express();
var timer = null;

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
   // remove this line if you are not using HTML5 routing
   if(timer) clearInterval(timer);

   req.on('close', function() { if(timer) clearInterval(timer) });
   next();
});

app.get('/app', function(req, res) {
   res.send("this is app page");
 });


app.get('/tracking', function(req, res) {

    timer= setInterval(function() {
        console.log("Tracking Start between 20 second interval")
    }, 20000);

    res.send('this is a tracking page!');  
});

//Lets define a port we want to listen to
const PORT = 3001;

app.listen(PORT);
console.log('Magic happens on port ' + PORT);
```

Something like this could work.
I don't know if you are using HTML5 routing (without reloading). But you can remove a the part that I have commented if not, because I think event `close` will fire when reloading.

Comment: Nope ,it does not work... It's show loading page. Not see the 'this is a tracking!' in browser.

Comment: ah my bad I forgot `next()`in my middleware. I update my answer.